# VBA Code Locks Excel when ran, yet runs OK when Stepping through the code

Tags: excel, vba

hope all is well!

I posted this question on MrExcel, but thought it might gain more traction here.

I had an issue where I needed to filter the highest value, given a set.

That set was defined by rows equaling each other. For any given lat/long/timestamp I am given up to five values.
I have used a function to identify which item in each set has the highest value. This works.

The function is:

```
=IF(F13=MAX(IF($A:$A=A13, $F:$F)), "Yes", "No")
```

I would like to open each file, then run the script. So, I wrote a VBA to automate it. It worked initially, then started to freeze my unit. 
I am not sure why.

I pasted a link to a test file below:
[CSV Test File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BeslD2Szn-4IvhfltZ44tpw7K7nZcGXR?usp=sharing) But also used screenshots to provide insights without downloading a file.

[image: Original CSV File Screenshot]

Notice the exact same timestamps, for each one I want the highest value.

When pressing F8 and stepping through the code, I will have the following:
[image: Filtered Data Screenshot]

Which is correct, but when I run this as a script (without stepping) the CSV file flashes infinitely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code is shown below.

```
Sub FilterRSRP_From_CSV()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button

    ActiveSheet.Name = "OriginalData"

    Range("I8").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=IF(RC[-3]=MAX(IF(C1=RC[-8], C6)), ""Yes"", ""No"")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I8:I30000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("I8:I30000").Select

    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$I$1:$I$30000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Yes"
    Cells.Select
    Range("L19").Activate
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "FilteredData"
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Worksheets("OriginalData").Delete

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Workbooks.Close
```

Comment: I will read that post. A sample file is linked above, it will contain the VBA but I pasted it to this post also. Yes, I am looking for the MAX value given a set if numbers. That set is defined by identicle timestamps. The helper column was used to filter out all unneeded values. Are you saying there is a qucker way of doing this?

Comment: Understood. Ill revise my post to include the first few lines of the Excel file.

Comment: Remove the file - add screen shots instead.

Comment: Do you turn screen updating on again at the end of your code?

Comment: When you press **Ctrl+Break**, at which line the execution stops? (Try pressing it few times and then you may need wait for a few minutes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cleaned up your code for you to remove the selects and turn the lights back on at the end.

Where are you running this from? A personal macro workbook or a host book? You may get an alert at the end as you are bulk closing workbooks, you would be better to specify the books, set their `.Saved` property to true then close them and it will surpress the alert.

```
Sub FilterRSRP_From_CSV()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button

    ActiveSheet.Name = "OriginalData"

    Range("I8").FormulaArray = "=IF(RC[-3]=MAX(IF(C1=RC[-8], C6)), ""Yes"", ""No"")"
    Range("I8").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I8:I30000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("I:I").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$I$1:$I$30000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Yes"
    Cells.Copy

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "FilteredData"
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Columns("I:I").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Worksheets("OriginalData").Delete

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Workbooks.Close
End Sub
```

Also what is the "alert" button you are trying to avoid with turning displayalerts off, if it is just the save then we can get around that as I explained above and not need to blanket surpress all alerts from Excel.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was ill. Thank you kindly! Looks like Selection. is a bad form of writing (still reading up on that). I like how you replaced them all with Range("XX").  I also didn't know you can Cell.Copy without making any selection. As for the alert button, that was remnants of another version where Excel prompted a dialog box prior to deleting. I forget what I was deleting at the moment, but a dialog opened that I needed to suppress. But great catch, I forgot to turn them back on.